# How can I create the image and text in box shown in image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

[image]

In image there are cards with image and text in center. How can I do that using boot strap in MVC project.

Comment: Please elaborate on the issue at hand. I am unable to comprehend what You're trying to accomplish and how Your project is set up. If You provide more information someone may be able to help You.

Comment: Hi, i want to add box within that image and text .  A row has  5 boxes shown in image, i am new to bootstrap

Comment: You don't need Bootstrap for this - just normal HTML+CSS. I don't believe Bootstrap has a built-in style for this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just after the bootstrap structure it will as follows

HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <div class="box">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ffc000/000000/?text=a">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <div class="box">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ffc000/000000/?text=a">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <div class="box">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ffc000/000000/?text=a">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <div class="box">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ffc000/000000/?text=a">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <div class="box">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ffc000/000000/?text=a">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  padding: 1.25rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: .5rem 0;
}
```